# i cant find grub page in my laptop

Tags: installation, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I had two Operating System  in my laptop.**Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7**.

last day i reinstalled my Windows 7 in same partition c.
also i config a prtition for Ubuntu with swap & / & /boot area.

after reinstalling Windows 7 OS  i cant see Ubuntu grub for startup this OS  and i go directly to windows 7 .

how i can install grub for going to ubuntu???????

help me please...

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

download boot-repair-disk and run it . for details go through this:-

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

this will restore your grub file !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from the live CD.
2. Determine the partition number of your main partition. GParted can help you here. I'm going to assume in this answer that it's `/dev/sda2`, but *make sure you use the correct partition number for your system!*
3. Mount your partition:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  # make sure that sda2 is correct!
   ```
4. Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

   ```
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
   ```
5. `chroot` into your Ubuntu install:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
6. At this point, you're in your install, not the live CD, and running as root. Update grub:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```

   If you get errors, go to step 7. (Otherwise, it is optional.)
7. Depending on your situation, you might have to reinstall grub:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   update-grub # I'm not sure if this is necessary, but it doesn't hurt.
   ```
8. If everything worked without errors, then you're all set:

   ```
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```
9. At this point, you should be able to boot normally.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432)