# Ubuntu fail to start on a dual boot with Windows 7 on Vaio

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, vaio, grubrescue

I followed the instructions for the Ubuntu windows installer on my Sony Vaio laptop (model SVT131A11M). Upon restart I was prompt to choose the OS for boot (Win7 or Ubuntu), but then I shut down the machine and from the next boot, every time I choose to boot into Ubuntu, the GNU GRUB terminal appears with a `grub>` prompt.

Now I'm able to boot into Win7, but can't boot into Ubuntu properly. Why does it happen and how come I was able to start Ubuntu successfully the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Download Boot Repair and run it, it will restore your grub file. For more details see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

**Additional reference:** [i cant find grub page in my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194356/i-cant-find-grub-page-in-my-laptop/194359#194359)

Answer (score 0):

What tipe of partition directory did U made ntfs or ext4 for Ubuntu ? It's important because when U use Ubuntu in dual boot with windows it's indicated to make it ntfs so that u can run Ubuntu alongside with windows .